# How to close a window using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

How to close a window using jQuery for all browser compatibility?

```
<input type="button" 
       name="backButton" 
       value="Close" 
       style="background-color:#245f91; color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" 
       onclick="window.close();">
```

This `onclick` event is working in IE. Could you help me to write code in jQuery?

Comment: window.close is plain javascript. Nothing in jQuery will make it more cross browser. It is the browser itself that decides if it allows your script to close the window.

Answer (score 62):

```
$(element).click(function(){
    window.close();
});
```

Note: you can *not* close any window that you didn't opened with `window.open`.  Directly invoking `window.close()` will ask user with a dialogue box.

Answer (score 17):

just `window.close()` is OK, why should write in jQuery?

Answer (score 17):

You can only use the `window.close` function when you have opened the window using `window.open()`, so I use the following function:

```
function close_window(url){
    var newWindow = window.open('', '_self', ''); //open the current window
    window.close(url);
 }
```

Comment: I think that should be "newWindow.close(url);". But in any case, this worked great and should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Good answer. Yes, it should be "newWindow.close(url);". Why are you using the url parameter?

Comment: Sadly does not work in Edge. Works current Chrome (but Chrome seems to let any old link close a window) and works with IE 11.... Bugger.

Answer (score 4):

For IE: `window.close();` and `self.close();` should work fine.

If you want just open the IE browser and type

`javascript:self.close()` and hit enter, it should ask you for a prompt.

Note: this method doesn't work for Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work for windows which are opened by using window.open(); method. Try this

```
var tmp=window.open(params);
tmp.close();
```